# EF core 3 using database without declarative referential integrity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

do we have a simple way to create relations in the code model only for using navigation or Include in LINQ in my service when my main Database do not have any FK! Its on old DB use by an old program, so I can't add FK ou PK inside SQL. I use Scaffold to retrieve my tables:

```
public partial class UsagerEw
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ModeLogin { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string ParamRole { get; set; }
    public string EmpContact { get; set; }
    public byte RestreintCommContrat { get; set; }
    public byte RestreintProjet { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte Inactif { get; set; }
    public byte Administrateur { get; set; }
    public string PasswordTemp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordTempExp { get; set; }
    public int CodeInt { get; set; }
    public int? IdSuperviseur { get; set; }
    public byte? EstSuperviseur { get; set; }
    public byte? LectureSeule { get; set; }
    public byte? DoitChangerPw { get; set; }
    public string PermsGrps { get; set; }
    public string ParamRole2 { get; set; }
    public Guid? Adguid { get; set; }
}

public partial class RefreshToken
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByIp { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Revoked { get; set; }
    public string RevokedByIp { get; set; }
    public string ReplaceByToken { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking use fluent code to create "Model side" relationship like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RefreshToken>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedByIp)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReplaceByToken).HasMaxLength(400);

            entity.Property(e => e.RevokedByIp).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.Token)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(400);

            entity.HasOne<UsagerEw>(r => r.UsagerEW).WithMany(u => u.RefreshTokens).HasForeignKey(r => r.UsagerEWId);
        });
```

But I think I will need to manually add some virtual properties on Entities Table?
It is a correct way to do this? And if so, where do I need to put my fluent code? Scaffold add it into OnModelCreating, but if I understand correctly, this function is called when I migrate back the code to DB? I will not migrate model back to DB, I just need to use relations "in memory" in my core service.

Sorry for my bad English. I hope my post is clear?

***** EDIT 1

I add navigation propertie in Usager EW like

```
public ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
```

and in my RefreshToken

```
public int UsagerEWId { get; set; }
public UsagerEw UsagerEw { get; set; }
```

to match my fluent relationship. I got: SqlException: Invalid column name 'UsagerEWId'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework will need to be configured with a Key to know how to uniquely identify a row. This does not need to actually be a Primary Key on a table, it can be made up of columns that can uniquely distinguish rows from each other.  So in you UsagerEw table, if Email is expected to unique across users (how they log in) then this could be defined as the Key, even if it isn't a PK in the database. If it takes a combination of columns then you can define all as Key and specify a ColumnOrder. (I.e. use Email and Code)

Navigation Properties are for entity to entity relationships. These are useful for LINQ queries to establish relationships (FKs) between entities so that you can query between the entities without explicit join expressions. They are optional if all you care about is the relationship.

For example if I have an Order, and Orders have an OrderStatus:

I can define Order as:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // ...

    [ForeignKey("OrderStatus")]
    public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

This way I can either eager load the OrderStatus with my order:

```
var order = context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderStatus).Single(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
```

... so that I can get at the OrderStatus properties such as `order.OrderStatus.Name`. The navigation property does not need to be `virtual`, but it will mean that if I try to access OrderStatus without eager loading it (`.Include(x => x.OrderStatus)) then I will probably get a NullReferenceException. EF *will* populate OrderStatus *if* it happens to have it cached. This can lead to somewhat inconsistent and conditional exceptions.

By declaring the property as `virtual`, if we forget to use `Include` and access the property, EF will go to the DB again if necessary provided the Order object is still within the scope of its DbContext. (Context not disposed) This helps avoid unexpected exceptions but it can often be a significant performance hit if abused. (being lazy with lazy loads)

By default I recommend declaring the properties as virtual as it's generally better to know the code should work consistently (and investigate performance issues) than having it potentially fail with exceptions inconsistently. Overall I recommend using Linq projection to populate view models / DTOs using `Select` which EF will compose the relevant Joins automatically without needing eager loading or tripping lazy loading.

If we really don't care about accessing properties from OrderStatus through the Order, we can just map the FK and have no navigation property. For something like OrderStatus we may use an `enum` which is descriptive enough in the code, and if there are only a handful of statuses, these could be pre-loaded and cached by the app to be queried if needed for things like a Description etc.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    //...

    public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

When it comes to configuration for existing databases you have 3 options:

1. Annotations /w attributes in the entity definitions.
2. Using the modelBuilder on the `DbContext.OnModelCreating`
3. Using `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementing classes and registering them on `DbContext.OnModelCreating`

For simple schemas and EF managed schemas, Attributes are typically enough, with modelBuilder handling the non-default stuff. For larger or more complex schemas with lots of relationships I prefer using `IEntityTypeConfiguration` as it helps keep the configuration organized.

Comment: Do you think using include and virtual properties will have a big impact  on performance? Do you prefer using JOIN instead?

Comment: Simply having navigation properties, virtual or otherwise, won't have any impact on performance on their own. Where people get caught out is either relying intentionally or unintentionally on lazy loading. (Leading to decisions like "eager load everything" and/or "turn off lazy loading") If you use projection correctly with `Select` then navigation properties result in very efficient and well performing queries /w their respective joins done automatically for you. I default to ensuring nav properties are virtual to avoid exceptions, I debug with profilers which help highlight query issues.

Comment: I see. I try to add navigation properties and I got the error. See Edit1. any advice? Thanks

Comment: The fields in the entity need to map to columns in the data tables. The RefreshToken has a UserId column, though it's not clear how this might map to a UsagerEw or some other table if UsagerEw isn't using a UserId or Id column. How do you currently select Refresh Tokens for a User record?

Comment: It is normal that when I do a Scaffold from many tables some table got an entity.HasKey(e=>e.CodeInt) and some table do not have HasKey (often table that got a column with Id name) but in DB the PK is set. Same thing for "normal" field. Some got a .IsRequired and .HaxMaxLength some SQL filed with on Allow null to false don't. What is the scaffold output? I was wondering all SQL field should get a fluent part created?

Comment: EF can work out things like PKs and FKs by convention, though I tend to explicitly configure them to avoid surprise behaviour. For regular properties on entities unless you want to apply rules (max length, is required for strings, etc) or transforms (changing the column name) then you don't need to define them in the configuration. Any field in your entity class will expect to map to a column in the associated table unless EF is told to ignore it. Every non-nullable field in the table should be declared in your entity if you expect to be able to insert rows.

Comment: Entities otherwise do not need to declare fields for every column in the table, so you can use simpler entities associated to purpose-built DbContexts, (see: Bounded DbContexts) with just the fields you care about, especially for read-focused operations. This can be a performance benefit for areas of the application that need to do a large amount of data reading or modifications as the DbContexts are tracking fewer, and simpler entities.

Answer (score 1):

> But I think I will need to manually add some virtual properties on
> Entities Table? It is a correct way to do this?

You do not need to add `virtual` for properties, if you do not plan to use Lazy Loading.
Scaffolding generates partial classes, so just create the same class in other file  of the same model's project and add needed navigation properties.

> Scaffold add it into OnModelCreating, but if I understand correctly,
> this function is called when I migrate back the code to DB?

Nope, for correct work, EF called this function for configuring Model and you need this call. No Schama changes will occur if you do not add migrations or recreate database by EF functions, like `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`.
So `OnModelCreating` function is important. If next Scaffold erases your code - you have to return it back somehow (not a big expert in EF and maybe community can propose better solution).

Comment: Ok, but I try to make an breakpoint into OnMOdelCreating, then instantiate my context in the startup.cs file with the services.AddDbContext(...) then using and an small query to DB. The breakpoint is never called.